# how to take screenshot of layout underneath

Tags: android

How to take a screenshot of layout underneath by making the layout transparent .I have tried that but it only gives the screenshot of views available inside the layout.Is it possible to do that.Because I am using the layout with `windowManager` in service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmapToShare = Bitmap.createBitmap(layoutToShare.getWidth(),layoutToShare.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapToShare);
layoutToShare.draw(canvas);
```

And You have bitmap from your layout.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer I have tried this code it takes the layout screenshot perfectly but even if I had set the layout to transparent it doesn't take the screenshot  of behind the layout as well .

Comment: layout color is ignored. You need set color on canvas  canvas.drawColor(color);

Comment: that means even if I set the layout to transparent it will not able to take screenshot of behind the layout?